# Using ternary operators with boolean return function in java

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-operator

```
boolean value = getResult();
if(value)
    count1++;
else
    count2++;
```

How to optimize it using ternary operator

Comment: There's nothing to optimize there. It's fine as it is and the conditional operator is meant to return a result, not for side effects.

Comment: The complexity will stay the same, you could only play code golf

Comment: Something to be aware of: using a ternary can cause unintended promotion of arguments, e.g. `return true ? Integer.parseInt(0) : Double.parseInt(0)` would always return a `Double` (on a method with a `Number` return type, for instance).

Answer (score 1):

Ternary operator is used to choose a value, not a variable.

```java
public void someFunc(Boolean multiplied) {
    Integer counter = multiplied?1:2; //chooses a value 1 or 2 depending on boolean
}
```

Sticking to common if-else is the best solution here. However, if you reallt want to go with a ternary operator (and I do not recommend doing this) you can do the following:

```java
boolean value = getResult();
Integer[] counters = new Integer[] {0, 0};
counters[value?0:1]+=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

In case your if statement grows and you have a great number of variables that you want to modify dynamically, look into the [Map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) data structure, in Java specifically, the implementation you'll most likely end up using is [HashMap](https://www.baeldung.com/java-hashmap).

However, in this case, using a Map is absolutely oversized and only reduces the safety of your code and readability.